# Invalid Block issue in rewrite Sales Order Grid in Magento 1.8

Tags: magento-1.8, blocks, overrides, order-grid

I am getting error of Invalid block on Live site but same code is working in Local system. Can anyone help me in getting out from this ASAP.

Below is my code:

**Config.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
  <modules>
    <Wildnet_Customsalesgrid>
      <version>0.1.0</version>
    </Wildnet_Customsalesgrid>
  </modules>
  <global>
    <helpers>
      <customsalesgrid>
        <class>Wildnet_Customsalesgrid_Helper</class>
      </customsalesgrid>
    </helpers>
    <events>
        <sales_order_grid_collection_load_before>
            <observers>
                <customsalesgrid>
                    <type>model</type>
                    <class>Wildnet_Customsalesgrid_Model_Observer</class>
                    <method>salesOrderGridCollectionLoadBefore</method>
                </customsalesgrid>
            </observers>
        </sales_order_grid_collection_load_before>
    </events>
    <blocks>
        <adminhtml>
            <rewrite>
                <sales_order_grid>Wildnet_Customsalesgrid_Block_Adminhtml_Sales_Order_Grid</sales_order_grid>
            </rewrite>
        </adminhtml>
    </blocks>
  </global>
</config>
```

**Grid.php**

```
<?php

class Wildnet_Customsalesgrid_Block_Adminhtml_Sales_Order_Grid extends Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Sales_Order_Grid {


    protected function _prepareColumns() {

        $this->addColumnAfter('customer_email', array(
                'header' => Mage::helper('customer')->__('Customer Email'),
                'index' => 'email',
                'type' => 'text',
        ), 'shipping_name');

        return parent::_prepareColumns();
    }

}
```

**Observer.php**

```
<?php

class Wildnet_Customsalesgrid_Model_Observer
{

   public function salesOrderGridCollectionLoadBefore(Varien_Event_Observer $observer) {

       /** @var Mage_Sales_Model_Resource_Order_Grid_Collection $collection */
       $collection = $observer->getEvent()->getOrderGridCollection();

       $collection->getSelect()->join(
           array('customer_table' => $collection->getTable('customer/entity')),
           'main_table.customer_id = customer_table.entity_id',
           'email'
       );
   }
}
```

This code is working fine in local without any issue but in Live it is showing Invalid block error.

Comment: i hope definitely some case sensitive issue is there

Comment: but this code is working in local system, i am uploading same code on live but it's not working. Suggest please ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Before installing any new extension on Live, Disable the compilation from `System -> Tools -> Compilation ->Disable`.

Disable cache also and install new extension after installation the run the compilation and enable the cache.

**Note:** After installation run compilation don't enable it. Compilation will automatically enable otherwise you will get Fatal error and site will be down.